# Make an object rotate and move towards a touch in Kivy

Tags: python, animation, rotation, kivy

I'm having a bit of trouble getting an object in a game I'm developing to move towards a touch in Kivy. Here is my code so far:

```
class Player(Widget):
angle = NumericProperty(0)

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
    x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
    calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
    new_angle = calc if calc > 0 else 360+calc

    self.angle = new_angle
    self.pos = [touch.x - 50, touch.y - 50]
```

What I want is that when the user touches (and holds the screen), the "player" continually rotates to match the position of the touch and moves gradually towards the touch. Suggestions?
I'll keep working and let you know what I use.

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

EDIT:
Since posting, I've tried this and it works much better... but the object stops moving often a few pixels from the cursor, to the side. I want it to stop so the cursor should be directly above... i.e. the player's finger on a mobile device would be holding it.

```
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
    x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
    calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
    new_angle = calc if calc > 0 else 360+calc

    self.angle = new_angle
    anim = Animation(x = touch.x, y = touch.y)
    anim.start(self)
```

Comment: When you say "continually rotates to match the position of the touch", do you mean the player rotates to face the touched location? What do you mean by "continually"?

Comment: Yes, "rotates to face the touched location". Please see my edit though, that bit sort of works not but it seems rather erratic and inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple example:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.graphics import Rotate
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

from math import atan2, degrees, abs

from kivy.animation import Animation

Builder.load_string('''                                                                                                                                        
<PlayerImage>:                                                                                                                                                 
    canvas.before:                                                                                                                                             
        PushMatrix                                                                                                                                             
        Rotate:                                                                                                                                                
            angle: self.angle                                                                                                                                  
            axis: (0, 0, 1)                                                                                                                                    
            origin: self.center                                                                                                                                
    canvas.after:                                                                                                                                              
        PopMatrix                                                                                                                                              
''')

class PlayerImage(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        angle = degrees(atan2(touch.y - self.center_y, 
                              touch.x - self.center_x))

        Animation(center=touch.pos, angle=angle).start(self)


root = Builder.load_string('''                                                                                                                                 
Widget:                                                                                                                                                        
    PlayerImage:                                                                                                                                               
        source: 'colours.png'                                                                                                                                  
        allow_stretch: True                                                                                                                                    
        keep_ratio: False                                                                                                                                      
''')

runTouchApp(root)
```

This only does the very basics, but maybe it can help you answer your question.

One big thing you might want to change is that using Animations is a bit inflexible. If this is a dynamic kind of game, this task would probably be better for your game update loop, moving and rotating incrementally each tick. Amongst other things, this would be more flexible to changes, and make it easier to move/rotate at a constant rate rather than in this case always taking 1s exactly.

Of course there are other minor things, like making the angle wrap around from -pi to pi instead of rotating nearly all the way if that happens.